# "Invalid Module Instantiation" Error in Mealy sequence detector - Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have defined a module for a Mealy State Machine that detects a particular sequence. I haven't encoded states as is usually a better choice as I wanted to do it the other way(I saw a similar example in a book, but the code was in VHDL).

```
module seq_detector(y_out,Clk,x_in);
  output y_out;
  reg y_out;
  input x_in, Clk;
  reg Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4;
  always @(posedge Clk)
    Q1 <= (Q1&&(!Q3))||((!Q1)&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(!Q4)&&(x_in));
    Q2 <= ((!Q3)&&Q4;&&(!x_in))||(Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(!Q4)&&x_in);
    Q3 <= Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(x_in);
    Q4 <= (Q1&&Q2;&&(x_in))||(Q1&&(!Q4)&&(!x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q2)&&(Q4)&&(!x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q2)&&(x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q3)&&Q4;&&x_in)||(Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q4)&&x_in);

  always @(x_in or Q1 or Q2 or Q3 or Q4)
  y_out <= Q3||(Q2&&(!Q4)&&x_in);
endmodule
```

On compiling the code, I get the following errors.

```
mini_project.v:8: syntax error
mini_project.v:8: error: Invalid module instantiation
mini_project.v:9: error: Invalid module instantiation
mini_project.v:10: error: Invalid module instantiation
```

I can't make out anything of the error message. Can someone please explain the error message and suggest how to correct it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing begin and end keywords in your always block.  The code thinks that you are trying to instantiate a module rather than do signal assignments.  Only the first line will be captured under the always block (the Q1 assignment).  The others will not.  Try this:

```
always @(posedge Clk)
begin
  Q1 <= (Q1&&(!Q3))||((!Q1)&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(!Q4)&&(x_in));
  Q2 <= ((!Q3)&&Q4;&&(!x_in))||(Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(!Q4)&&x_in);
  Q3 <= Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(x_in);
  Q4 <= (Q1&&Q2;&&(x_in))||(Q1&&(!Q4)&&(!x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q2)&&(Q4)&&(!x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q2)&&(x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q3)&&Q4;&&x_in)||(Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q4)&&x_in);
end
```

As a side note, this code is really really really ugly.  Is there a better way to do this??

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that. The code compiles perfectly now. Thank you !
Regarding the side-note, I totally agree with you(I would probably add couple of extra reallys' to your sentence), but I am new to Verilog and wanted to just code directly from the state equations and verify that I get the same output by the usual method and this one.

Comment: This code is not legal Verilog syntax, as my Answer explains.  Your compiler should generate errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple syntax errors.

You need a `begin/end` in your `always` block.

```
  always @(posedge Clk) begin
    Q1 <= (Q1&&(!Q3))||((!Q1)&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(!Q4)&&(x_in));
    Q2 <= ((!Q3)&&Q4;&&(!x_in))||(Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(!Q4)&&x_in);
    Q3 <= Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(x_in);
    Q4 <= (Q1&&Q2;&&(x_in))||(Q1&&(!Q4)&&(!x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q2)&&(Q4)&&(!x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q2)&&(x_in))||((!Q1)&&(!Q3)&&Q4;&&x_in)||(Q1&&Q2;&&(!Q4)&&x_in);
  end
```

Even after fixing that, you have stray semicolons all throughout your code:

```
Q1 <= (Q1&&(!Q3))||((!Q1)&&Q2;&&(!Q3)&&(!Q4)&&(x_in));
// ---------------------------
```

Comment: Err, aren't those semicolons necessary ? I compiled without them and got a syntax error. I am using Verilog 1995 syntax, maybe it is as you say in the newer syntax ?

Comment: The code I posted still has compile errors for me.  Semicolons are used for ending a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally this is a current assignment in my CPE166 advanced logic design class.  The main idea in the assignment is to synthesize registers correctly.  Something like this (though our assignment was much more complicated with multiple possible inputs, longer sequences, reset, programmable sequences, and buttons which needed to be debounced):

```
module sequence_detector(
input wire x_in,clk,
output wire y_out 
);

reg [3:0] seq, seq_nxt;

parameter correct_sequence = 4'b1001;

always @(posedge clk) 
    seq <= seq_nxt;

always @(*)
    seq_nxt = {seq[2:0] , x_in};

assign y_out = (seq == correct_sequence);
endmodule
```

This will create a 4-bit shift register which will shift on every positive clock edge.  The newest value of x_in will go in on one side and the oldest value of x_in will be shifted out.  The current values of the shift register are constantly compared to the parameter `correct_sequence`, which when true will make y_out go high.

[image: Synthesized Logic]